# Splicing new wire into existing home wiring

Tags: wiring, receptacle

I want to replace the receptacles in my home and when I removed some old receptacles I noticed that many of the wires are very short making replacing the receptacles quite difficult as most of the wires don't reach out of their respective receptacle box. Is there anything wrong, code or otherwise, with connecting new 12 gauge wire (color coded to match existing wire color) to the receptacles and splicing that in to the home wiring with [push in connectors](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/111411/27099)? Thank you.

Comment: By "push in connector" do you mean a Wago-type multi-wire connector?

Comment: I mean like the one you mentioned previously. [Link](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/111408/attaching-three-copper-wires-together-without-using-a-wire-nut)

Comment: Yup -- that's the same thing I refer to when I say "Wago-type connector"

Comment: Apologies, I did not realize that was another name for them.

Comment: I assume this is copper wire, right? My tract house was thrown up in 1970 with aluminum wire and they did not leave the standard 6 inches past the wall. Two or 3 inches or less in some cases. This made pig-tailing with copper a trial.  But your wires sound even shorter! This is going to be troublesome and/or expensive to deal with unless these WAGO push-in connectors will work, which I doubt. Maybe you could relocate some boxes to get slack? AFIK home inspectors remove cover plates, but do NOT pull out receptacles or use any other means to determine the length of conductor in boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem with your plan.  However, if you have aluminum wiring, you're going to have to use connectors listed for AL.

Comment: +1 The illustrated connectors effectively allow the addition of one or more pigtails. I prefer using a connector that leaves one extra opening in case an additional pigtail is needed at a later time. Howver there are push-in connectors that are meant to merely extend a single wire. See [this example](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Ideal-Spliceline-42-Orange-In-Line-Push-In-Butt-Splices-10-Pack-30-1342S/202894306)